# Not clickable point (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to click the "Show more" button, but I can't.

Any help? Thank you very much.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.scorespro.com/basketball/china/cba/results/')
time.sleep(2)
showmore = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Show more")
showmore.click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dividing the height with some number can decrease the scroll height and will stop where `Show More` visible**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.scorespro.com/basketball/china/cba/results/')
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/1.35);")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("show_more").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are after the tables, you don't need to use Selenium. you can pull the data straight away with requests, and parse with pandas.

To find that, when you go to the page, you want to right-click and 'Inspect' (or Shft-Ctrl-I). This will open a side panel. When it opens, you want to go to `Network` and `XHR`. And you want to sort of browse those requests (and you can click on `Preview` to see what it return. You may need to 1) reload the page; and 2) click around the table. For example, once I clicked "show more" at the bottom of the table, it popped up.

Once you find it, click on `Headers` and you'l see the url and payload, etc. I highlighted it in the pic for you:

[image]

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.scorespro.com/basketball/ajaxdata_more.php'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Mobile Safari/537.36'}


dfList = []
for season in ['2018-2019','2019-2020']:
    continueLoop = True
    page = 1
    while continueLoop == True:
        print ('%s Collecting Page: %s' %(season,page))
        payload = {
        'country': 'china',
        'comp': 'cba',
        'season': season,
        'status': 'results',
        'league': '',
        'page': '%s' %page}
    
    
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
        
        try:
            dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)
        except ValueError:
            print ('No more tables found.')
            continueLoop = False
            
        page+=1
        dfList.extend(dfs)

dfList_single = []
cols = ['Date','Final Time', 'Team', 'Final Score','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','OT','Half Time Score','Combined Total Score']
for each in dfList:
    each = each.loc[:,[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
    each.columns = cols
    teamA = each.iloc[0,:]
    teamB = each.iloc[1,2:]
    temp_df = pd.concat([teamA, teamB], axis=0).to_frame().T
    dfList_single.append(temp_df)


df = pd.concat(dfList_single)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.head(10).to_string())
             Date Final Time      Team  Final Score  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Half Time Score  Combined Total Score
0  15.08.20 15:00         FT  Guandong          123  26  28  41  28               54                   238
1  15.08.20 15:00         FT  Liaoning          115  29  18  39  29               47                   238
2  13.08.20 15:00         FT  Liaoning          115  34  24  23  34               58                   228
3  13.08.20 15:00         FT  Guandong          113  38  28  27  20               66                   228
4  11.08.20 15:00         FT  Guandong          110  25  30  25  30               55                   198
5  11.08.20 15:00         FT  Liaoning           88  24  26  23  15               50                   198
6  08.08.20 15:00         FT  Guandong           88  16  21  26  25               37                   173
7  08.08.20 15:00         FT   Beijing           85  13  24  20  28               37                   173
8  07.08.20 15:00         FT  Liaoning          119  22  40  29  28               62                   232
9  07.08.20 15:00         FT  Xinjiang          113  33  22  34  24               55                   232
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

What should I do if I want some seasons together? For example, season 2018/2019 and 2019/2020.

Comment: You could use that parameter in the payload, and iterate. I’ll show you an example. tomorrow

Comment: Thank you @chitown88. If I want to put each match in a same line, what should I do? With selenium, I search the css selector and I can put each one in a column, but with this loop I can't figure it out.

Comment: what do you mean? not sure I understand what you want? so instead of 2 rows per match, just 1 row?

Comment: Yes! @chitown88

Comment: @EnriqueRamirezMoreno ok try now

Comment: Simply marvelous.@chitown88 I didn't know anything about pulling data from ajaxdata_more.php. Can I find any tutorial somewhere? Thank you so much

Comment: I'm trying to do the same with 'soccer' but I can't. Why doesn't it work if I change 'basketball' for 'soccer'?

Comment: I've just figure it out how to make it with soccer. Thank you very much for all. One last question @chitown88 Where did you get this url: 'https://www.scorespro.com/basketball/ajaxdata_more.php'?

Comment: @EnriqueRamirezMoreno, glad you figured out soccer, I was going to answer this morning (I usually stay away from the laptop over the weekend). I added how to find the url in the solution above

Comment: Hehe. I supossed so. Thank you so much. You have been really useful for me. Glad you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Two issue with your code:
First you are trying to scroll after clicking, where as it should be before. Second You are using height of screen which may work in one device bit not in other if size varies.
Better way is to scroll to element itself and the click. See below code. It worked fine:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome('..\drivers\chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.scorespro.com/basketball/china/cba/results/")
driver.maximize_window()
# I have accept cookies on page , so below step
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Agree']"))).click()
showMore = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Show more")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", showMore)
time.sleep(2)
showMore.click()
```